# M'Doraisa how many strings of tzitzis does one need?

Tags: tzitzis

Nowadays a *beged* (i.e. garment) with tzitzis has 4 strings on each corner that are then tied in such a way so it comes out as 8 strings altogether hanging down. It is then connected to the beged with 5 knots and a number of times wrapped around between each knot (with various *minhagim* (i.e. customs) on how to tie the tzitzis exactly.)

This is what we do now, however *M'Doraisa* (i.e. Biblically) what does a beged with tzitzis look like? How many strings would satisfy the requirement M'Doraisa? Would one string (tied in a single knot -- *kesher elyon d'oraisa* (the top kesher in min hatorah) and hanging down as 2 fulfill it? Do we need 4 (doubled to 8) strings M'Doraisa?

Comment: I would assume that all 4 strings are required M'Deoraisa, by the fact that the Tzitzis become Pasul if even 1 string is missing, while there are many other elements that could be missing and the Tzitzis would still be Kosher B'Dieved (like the knots 2-5 you mentioned, one end (half a string) being ripped).

Comment: @Salmononius2 Why would you assume that? Can't it be Pasul Miderabanan and still be Pasul?

Comment: @Salmononius2 That's true however perhaps only according to Shulchan Aruch which might be only m'drabbanan. It's exactly the question though, do we say all 4 strings are d'oraisa?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=41b&format=pdf

Comment: It seems to me that OP is confusing m'doraisa with "in Torah SheB'al Peh." The k'sav is not explicit, but the gemara very much is.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, maybe the OP just isn't familiar with the relevant Gemara? Turn it into an answer!

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky It doesn't seem that way to me.

Comment: @DoubleAA For reference, can you give an example of a Pasul midirabanan on a mitzvah di'oraisa?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Skipping referencing King David in Benching. A Sukkah with dirty pots in it.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure that's "within the tzura," since the text is only dirabanan anyhow, even though the mitzvah is di'oraisa. (You edited your comment before I published mine, the second example is definitely a better one.)

Answer (score 2):

MiD'oreisa you need four strings. In Menachos the gemara learns this out the *posuk* (Devarim 22:12). The Mishnah Berurah explains this in O.C. 11, 11, 58.

To have kosher tzitzis you have to tie the first double knot, do at least three wrappings and then tie a second double knot. The Mishnah Berurah (ibid. 66) explains that if you do this you meet the minimum requirement min HaTorah and can rely on this in a bind (no pun intended) if it's getting really close to Shabbos.

Comment: Many that wear techeles and tie like the Rambam only have one knot at the top and nothing at the bottom. Why is this?

Comment: Shammai says that you only need three strings, rather than the four called for by Hillel.

Comment: Yeshoshua - MiD'oreisa you need to have a knot and windings. There's a safek whether the critical knot is at the top or the bottom. Most hold that it's the top knot. According to some opinions Rambam knots may not have a din of the required knot, so those who do not have a mesora from the Rambam might be choshesh and add a double knot, or even one at the top and another at the bottom, to play it safe. Another answer is that it's simply more pragmatic to make a double knot before you start tying the chulyoth. I'm pretty sure most Temanim tie a double knot before the chulyoth.